# How to find PYTHONPATH on Redhat?

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

On Redhat, python 2.4.3 is installed. On that machine, we have an application that uses python 2.6 (strange, at least for me).

I understand it this way:
I start a command line from RedHat desktop and type "python", it says:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Dec 11 2006, 11:39:03)
```

Within the application I mentioned above, I can start an xterm, and when I type "python" there, it says:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Sep 27 2010, 19:19:43)
```

Now, PYTHONPATH of RedHat and PYTHONPATH of this application is different than each other.

I want to add a new directory to the PYTHONPATH of this application. How can I find where its PYTHONPATH is defined? And how do I add a new directory to this application's PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Have you got several version of python in bin directories. Normaly you'll have python and python2.x .

Comment: I will install numpy and matplotlib packages. And write scripts using these 2 packages for this application. I don't have root privileges. I think I have 2 options: 1-install these packages to `~/.local` or 2-copy these libraries to one of the directories listed in applications' PYTHONPATH. My main question is: Do I have to run setup.py to install numpy and matplotlib? Why not just copy modules of these packages to one of the directories listed in PYTHONPATH of the application?

Comment: Don't do 2. Just update your PYTHONPATH. And you can't just copy the modules, some C and Fortran libraries are compiled during the build process.

Comment: I installed numpy to ~/.local using python 2.4.3. Then I started application's python and typed `sys.path.append("/home/myuser/.local/lib64/python2.4/site-packages")` When I try to `import numpy`, it said: `ImportError: /home/myuser/.local/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multia
rray.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the application might be running inside some python virtual environment.

You should focus your research trying to find out which python is being used when you run python. You can do it using the which comamand.

```
which python
```

The both values will be definitely different.

Now, before adding a new path to the app PYTHONPATH you should ask before why you need it. If you only need a python module it might be better to just install it from pip.

If you still need to do it you can do it with the python site. Have you look on it has your answer. http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to find where the `PYTHONPATH` is defined because it's likely defined in several places (it could be defined or modified in any script that runs when your shell starts). If you want to add a directory to the path, in your script you can append a string representing that directory to [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Comment: How can I represent that directory to sys.path?

Comment: @alwbtc it's just a string. So if you wanted to add `/usr/local/bin`, you'd write `sys.path.append('/usr/local/bin')`.